# How do I fix the error where nothing is printing when I run my code in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, printing, output

I had some issues with running my code whereby nothing is being printed, just what is shown below:
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\Musa\Documents\Coding Files\Python\Practise File.py"

[Done] exited with code=0 in 1.013 seconds

In between the two lines is where the code should print but nothing is there. I am using python to interpret my code. I wrote a simple "hello world" to test it out but still, nothing is printed out. There are no errors detected on my code.

[Visual representation of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRE7b.png)

Comment: Hi. My code was a simple 
print("hello world")

Comment: The VSCode image indicates that your file has outstanding changes? Try saving it and running it again? You probably also want to switch to the "terminal" tab.

Comment: thank you so much. this helped. one more thing, if I want to switch to terminal, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can click the triangle button in the upper right corner called “Run python file”
And view the output results in the terminal which is two on the right of “out put”